# Merge fields in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array, and i need to re-arrange it in order to can send it to some another function.....
here is actual array, that i take direct from sql :

```
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(4) "product1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "BE"
        ["total"]=>
        string(2) "45"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(4) "product1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "BG"
        ["total"]=>
        string(2) "31"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(4) "product1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "CZ"
        ["total"]=>
        string(2) "48"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(4) "product1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "DE"
        ["total"]=>
        string(2) "58"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(4) {
        ["product"]=>
        string(4) "product1"
        ["country"]=>
        string(2) "DK"
        ["total"]=>
        string(2) "39"
      }
    }
```

This is the expected array:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_country"]=> string(4) "product1_BE"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "45"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_country"]=> string(4) "product1_BG"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "31"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_country"]=>string(4) "product1_CZ"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "48"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_country"]=>string(4) "product1_DE"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "58"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["product_country"]=> string(4) "product1_DK"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "39"
  }
}
```

So, I need to merge colunms "product" + "country"
so key would be changed to "product_country" and value to "Productvalue_countryValue"
Then remove "country" from the array

How i can do it in simple and fast function?
This function will run an array with more than 12k positions.

Comment: @Nirnae trying some foreach, and push it to new array, but far to be good

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through your array and place the modifications into a new array:

```
$array = //your first array

foreach($array as $a) $new_arr[] = array("product_country" => $a["product"]."_".$a["country"], "total" => $a["total"]);

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). It will iterate over your `array` and make new using `concatProductCountry` callback for every item in array.

```
$input = 
    array(
      array(
        "product" => "product1",
        "country" => "BE",
        "total" => "45"
      ),
      array(
        "product" => "product1",
        "country" => "BG",
        "total" => "31"
      )
    );

function concatProductCountry($item){
  return array(
    'product_country' => $item['product'] . '_' . $item['country'],
    'total' => $item['total']
  );
}

$newArray = array_map('concatProductCountry', $input);
var_dump($newArray);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product_country"]=>
    string(11) "product1_BE"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "45"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product_country"]=>
    string(11) "product1_BG"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "31"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop the actual array and create a new array based on the required array format

```
foreach($actualArray as $k => $val) {
    $newArr[$k]['product_country'] = $val['product'] . '_' . $val['country'];
    $newArr[$k]["total"]           = $val["total"];
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by calling multisort array,

```
<?php
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);
$sort=array_multisort($data);
print_r($data);
?>
```